# adding condition when case statement is true in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have a query that where i need to put condition when case statement is true.I have tried like this but not geeting the correct value.

```
SELECT
    name,count(CASE WHEN date_part('year',time_stamp) = 2016 THEN answ_count end) AS Year15 
FROM 
        companies companies 
where 

    (CASE when no_answer='f' then value_s IS  not  NULL or value_n IS  not  NULL end )
```

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name,
        count(CASE WHEN date_part('year',time_stamp) = 2016 THEN answ_count end) AS Year15 
FROM 
        companies companies 
where 
    CASE when no_answer='f' then value_s ELSE '1' end IS  not  NULL
    OR  CASE when no_answer='f' then value_n  ELSE '1' end IS  not  NULL
```

`CASE` is an expression, you can only specify a value after the `THEN` part, not a condition like you did `THEN value_s IS NOT NULL`

Comment: What are you expecting to get?

Comment: And also this error ERROR:  CASE types integer and text cannot be matched
LINE 27: ...             and( CASE when no_answer='f' then dp_valu...

Comment: getting no error but result is same as first query that i have posted

Comment: Then I'll ask you again, what do you get? and what do you expect to get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108359/discussion-between-sudarshan-and-sagi).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use case like that.

It's hard to figure out what you are trying to do, but test the result of the case, rather than putting the test inside the case, like this:

```
...
where CASE when no_answer='f' then value_s else value_n end
  IS not NULL
```

Comment: Condition i want to add is like when no_answer='f' then it should check whether value_s or value_n is not null elase it should not check for that condition